# How to post data to a table that has a many to many relationship in .Net 5

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have two tables with a many-to-many relationship and a link table. One is called taskSchedule and the other is called User. They are linked through a table called UserTask. One user can have many tasks assigned to them and one task can have many users assigned to them. I have run the dotnet ef database update command and it has successfully created the link table userTasks in the mysql database.

However, I am trying to get one of the APIs to post information to the taskSchedule table where it needs to add the user id and task id to the userTask link table. However I have no idea on how to do this.

below is the model for user.cs, taskschedule.cs and userTask.cs

user.cs

```
public class User: IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles {get; set;}
    public IList<userTask> UserTasks {get; set;}
}
```

TaskSchedule.cs

```
public class TaskSchedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? End { get; set; }
    public bool isClosed { get; set; }
    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
    public byte priorityLevel { get; set; }
    public bool hasTimeLimit { get; set; }       
    public Customer customer { get; set; }
    public int? customerId { get; set; }
    public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    public List<AttachmentFile> Attachments { get; set; }  

    //user currently assigned to the task 
    // public int? userCurrentAssignedId { get; set; } 
    // [ForeignKey("userCurrentAssignedId")]
    // public User userCurrentAssigned { get; set; }

    public List<userTask> UserTasks {get; set;}


    //user who last edited the task
    public int? userLastEditId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("userLastEditId")]
    public User userLastEdit { get; set; }
    public DateTime? userLastEditDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime taskCreatedDate { get; set; }

}
```

}

userTask.cs  // linktable

```
public class userTask
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int TaskScheduleId { get; set; }
    public TaskSchedule TaskSchedule { get; set; }
}
```

Controller to update record

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<TaskSchedule> PutSchedule(int id, [FromBody] TaskSchedule taskSchedule)
    {
        int tokenUserId = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
        taskSchedule.userLastEditId = tokenUserId; 

        DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Now;
        string NowDate =  thisDay.ToString("g");
        taskSchedule.userLastEditDate = Convert.ToDateTime(NowDate);

        if(taskSchedule.Start < taskSchedule.End || taskSchedule.Start == null && taskSchedule.End == null) {
            TaskSchedule taskSchedulePut = _repo.Update(id, taskSchedule);          
            return taskSchedulePut;
        }
        return BadRequest("start time is not less than end time");     
    }
```

repository

```
    public TaskSchedule Update(int Id, TaskSchedule taskSchedule) 
    {
        var TaskScheduleDb =  _context.TaskSchedules.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == Id);

        TaskScheduleDb.Title = taskSchedule.Title;
        TaskScheduleDb.Start = taskSchedule.Start;
        TaskScheduleDb.End = taskSchedule.End;

        TaskScheduleDb.userLastEditDate = taskSchedule.userLastEditDate;

   
    // this is where the userId needs to be updated on the usertable.       
        taskSchedule.UserTasks.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == taskSchedule.UserTasks.);
        taskSchedule.UserTasks[0].UserId = taskSchedule.UserTasks.;        


        _context.SaveChanges();

        return TaskScheduleDb;
    }
```

Where in the repository can I add the tokenUserId, coming from the controller, to the userId in the userTask link table? Furthermore, how do I add the taskId for the userTask link table if the taskId is only just being generated?

Comment: Could you post the full TaskSchedule class pls? I can't see for example userLastEditId  or userLastEditDate

Comment: I've edited the taskschedule class with the full properties.

Comment: Thanks, And I was wondering what is id in PutSchedule(int id,...). Is it UserId?

Comment: "id" is the id that belongs to the task in the database. it searches in the database for the task that has the same id and then gets that task updated.

Comment: UserId and TaskScheduleId are completely indipendent. You can't use TaskSchedule to obtain UserId. You have include UserId in PutSchedule, instead of TaskSchedule.Id. You have  TaskShceduleId in TaskSchedule object already. Can you post your View and Get action pls?

Comment: I assume you mean front end when you say view, that's done in a separate framework. I'm not sure what you mean when you say Get action. If it's the case that they are separate, does that mean that I have to manually enter the information into the userTask table?

Comment: I mean I don't see why you should update UserTask too. If only Task is chanded it is enough to save Task only. If you need to assign Task to another user it is a different story. What is the purpose of PutSchedule  action?

Comment: the purpose of PutSchedule is to update anything that changes in a record of PutSchedule, which includes linked information to the user table. Because of the way the front end is created, it has to update everything.

Comment: If you need to update User too you will need to post userId at least.  Show your view and action that created that view, I will see is it possible to fugure UserId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you need to update UserTask table too. So just replace

```
 taskSchedule.UserTasks.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == taskSchedule.UserTasks.);
 taskSchedule.UserTasks[0].UserId = taskSchedule.UserTasks.;  
 _context.SaveChanges();
```

with

```
_context.Entry(TaskScheduleDb).State=EntityState.Modified;
 _context.SaveChanges();
```